# Unfamiliar Application Running tsp2uvc.exe

Tags: windows-7, malware, malware-removal

I was going through my wife's computer today and I found an application running in the task manager called `tsp2uvc.exe`. I am unfamiliar with this application and so have killed it with the Process Explorer.

All attempts to Google it came up pointing to the same website, apparently it is the ONLY website that knows anything about this application. This of course raised some alarms.

The file is under `C:\Windows`, and I've looked with SysInternals' Autoruns but can't seem to find it so I'm not sure how it is getting started.

Does anyone have any information on this application?

Comment: have you checked the properties on the file for more information on its origins? The internet-at-large has never heard of that file.

Comment: What's with the downvote whoever did that? Please don't be an anonymous downvoter - explain so that people can improve if need be.

Comment: I had originally though that Frank Thomas above was the down voter, and as he explained what he found deficient in my question (even if I felt he might next time be a little more polite) I accepted the down vote. However, thanks for bringing things back to 0 Julian.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears to be something possibly related to a Sonix Digital Camera

According to CESAM, it is "probably" safe.

http://startups.cesam-antimalware.com/En/Files/tsnp2uvc.exe/1/

http://startups.cesam-antimalware.com/En/T/Page_26/